# create unique ids for jquery plugin instances?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have created a jQuery plugin which listens to window for blur events.

I want to create a unique id inside of the plugin itself so I can [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) the listener when I destroy instances of the plugin. How should I create these uniqueIds?

The example below clearly does not work -- incrementId in the destroy method is always removing blur from the last plugin instance.

```
 (function( $ ) {

    var incrementId = 0;

    var methods = 
    {
        init : function( options ) {
            var that = this;
            incrementId += 1;
            $(window).on( "blur.pleaseKillMe" + incrementId, function( e ) {
                that.css( "color", "red" );
            });
        },

        destroy : function( ) {
            console.log( "and... " + incrementId );
            $(window).off( "blur.pleaseKillMe" + incrementId );
        }
    };

    $.fn.pleaseKillMe = function( method )
    {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        }
        else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        }
        else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.p5shrinkwrap' );
        }
    };

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
incrementId += 1;
this.data('id', incrementId);
...
$(window).off('blur.pleaseKillMe' + this.data('id');
```